# Finding $E(Y)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y)$ given the conditional density of $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ have an exponential distribution with mean $\lambda$ and the conditional density of $Y$ given $X=x$ be
>
> $$
> f(y|x) = \left\{ 
>   \begin{array}{l l}
>     \frac{1}{x} & \quad \text{for $0 \leq y \leq x$}\\
>     0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
>   \end{array} \right.
> $$
>
> Find $E(Y)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y)$.

Now I have $E(Y)$ to be $x/2$ but I do now know how to get the variance. Any tips?

Comment: *Now I have E(Y) to be 2/x*... is a true mystery. First, this would be E[Y|X=x], not E[Y], second this would be x/2, not 2/x.

Comment: ah, i actually did have 2/x, editing

Comment: E(Y)=x/2 is still absurd, for the reason already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
First find the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X=x$ by calculating
$$
{\rm E}[Y\mid X=x]=\int_0^x y\cdot f(y\mid x)\,\mathrm dy.
$$
Then use the formula
$$
{\rm E}[Y]=\int {\rm E}[Y\mid X=x]\cdot f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx.
$$
For the variance, use a similar argument along with the formula $\mathrm{Var}(Y)={\rm E}[Y^2]-{\rm E}[Y]^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps:

1. $$E[Y |X=x]=\int_0^x y\cdot f(y| x)~dy$$ 2. $$E[Y]=\int_0^{\infty}E[Y |X=x]\cdot f_X(x)~dx$$ 3.$$\text{Var}[Y|X=x]=E[Y^2 |X=x]-(E[Y |X=x])^2$$ 4.$$\text{Var}[Y]=\text{Var}[E(Y|X)]+E[\text{Var}(Y|X)]$$